# "Помочь чем-то" или "помочь с чем-то"?

Tags: выбор-слов

Как правильно сказать (написать): помочь чем-то или помочь с чем-то?

Answer (score 1):

**Помочь чем-то** означает *помочь действиями или средствами* и указывает на **характер помощи** (напр. помочь рекомендательным письмом, советом, деньгами, своим трудом).

**Помочь с чем-то** означает *облегчить кому-то решение проблемы или выполнение работы* и указывает на **содержание задачи**, стоящей перед тем, кому помогают (напр. помочь с получением визы,  с продажей квартиры).
Близкое значение имеет выражение **помочь в чём-то**, с той разницей, что помощь направлена на *участие* в решении проблемы (в меньшей степени акцентирует *результат*, чем в варианте "**с чем-то**", который может подразумевать и решение проблемы силами помогающего), напр. **помочь в** уборке урожая на садовом участке, пособирав клубнику.

Answer (score 0):

Можно **помочь чем-то**, например: помочь советом, делом, словом.
Можно **помочь в чем-то**, например: помочь в тренировке, в беде.

Иногда в разговорной речи приходится слышать "**помочь с чем-то**" в смысле "помочь справиться с чем-то", например: *Помогите с домашним заданием по химии*.

Дополнение

**Помочь с чем-то** встречается и в ответах Грамоты:
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=268577
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=248962

Answer (score 0):

1. Если просто, то "помочь чем-то" - это "решить проблему **с помощью чего-то**", а "помочь с чем-то" - это "решить проблему, **связанную с чем-то**". То есть в "помочь чем-то" главное то, с помощью чего решить, в "помочь с чем-то" главное то, что вообще за пробему решать надо:

   > Помочь с вычислением радиуса сегмента - решить проблему, связанную с радиусом сегмента.

> Помочь дробью - решить проблему с помощью дроби.